# How to analyze Json data which is returned by WCF service in HTML using AJAX?

Tags: c#, html, ajax, json, wcf

Anyone can help me on how to get the data details from JSON model? 
I am using a WCF service which return a JSON type data. It runs well I am sure because I try it from WebClient.
But I want to show the data in my HTML site. I am using the following code, nothing help.
 success: function (msg) {

```
                    var result = eval("("+msg+")");
                    $.each(result.UserLoginResult.d,function(i,item){
                        alert(item.name);
                    });
```

It really hurt me, you know. 
So I beg your help here, I search from google for hours, No one example can help me. :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all. Finally, I found the problem and fix it. 
JQuery already return us Json object not a string, we needn't eval() at all. 
Just use msg.d[index][index]!

Happy coding,
Rocky

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the JSON.parse(msg) method?
Then you can simply console.log the answer and find out exactly what to do next.

Comment: I will try it. If it works, I will let you know. THanks

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample how you do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var jsonp = '[{"Lang":"jQuery","ID":"1"},{"Lang":"C#","ID":"2"}]';
  var lang = '';
  var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonp);
  $.each(obj, function() {
      lang += this['Lang'] + "<br/>";
  });
  $('span').html(lang);
});
```

​

out put: jQuery C#

or you can  use the $.getJSON method:

Comment: Our WCF returns like this: {"result":[{"BaseContactID":null,"Category":null,"Deleted":false,"Duties":null,"Errors":"Token is invalid","Name":null,"Project":null,"ProjectID":null,"Telephone":null,"Updated":false,"WorkAt":null}]}, It seems con't get the data. How to do with this?

Comment: it seesm you have invalid json data

Comment: .Net 3.5+ for　WCF　JSON format, It's the stand result. JQuery can use it directly. However, Thanks for your help